# Document.settings.set is undefined for object generated by createDocument

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm trying to persist a variable in Office.js on a dynamically created MSWord document.  The `set` method from `myNewDoc.settings.set` is undefined.

What am I missing?

```js
var openNewDocument = function (base64str) {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var myNewDoc = context.application.createDocument(base64str);
        context.load(myNewDoc);

        return context.sync().then(function () {
            myNewDoc.settings.set("DocumentId", "123");
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this question really so difficult?  I only want to set a variable in a new document?  Is there any help out there?

Comment: Could you use localStorage or sessionStorage to pass data to the new doc's addin?

Comment: I ended up adding a hidden content control to the document content with the DocumentId embedded until such time that the office context became available.

Can someone clarify why the ".set" method (amongst many others) isn't available for documents that have been created/opened this way?  It is as-if the functionality is somehow tied to the task pane, which for newly opened document such as this do not have the task pane loaded.  That's my theory for what it's worth

Comment: Another work around would be to automatically open a task pane, but even that seems impossible.  The following commands don't work for documents create via this method:

Office.context.document.settings.set("Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", true);

Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();

The method "saveAsync" just isn't available immediately after creation.   Some clarity would be greatly appreciated to describe what's actually going on here